# Meaning of 提頓 outside 書法

Tags: grammar, meaning, classical-chinese

I know that 提頓 has a certain meaning in calligraphy. Besides that, however, it appears in the definition of a few classical grammatical particles. For example, the Hanyu Da Cidian remarks on 耶：

> 助词。用于句末或句中。表示提顿

It seems that even some students in the Chinese 高考 are vexed by this and get very [evasive](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/3560397.html) answers.

Personally, I am inclined to interpret the combination of rising and pausing (that’s how I understand the word), as a pause that emphasises the immediately proceeding element.

But it would be nice to rely on something more substantial than my hunch.

On the other hand „提頓“ seems rare compared to ”停頓“。May it be a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a combination of 提问 and 停顿? All of my dictionaries agree that 耶 is primarily used for questioning. 耶：句末助词，表示疑问或反诘。(辞源 p. 3339, 王力字典 p. 980) It is also occasionally used in non-question sentences. (古代汉语虚词词典 p. 687)

From Scripta Sinica 萇楚齋隨筆續筆三筆四筆五筆／五筆／卷五／謝章鋌論文: 予嘗謂起承轉合，提頓呼應，此陋儒以之談制藝者，自茅鹿門以逮林西仲，乃以此治古文。

Here it should be clear that 提 and 頓 refer to two different things.

大唐西域記十二卷／卷五／憍賞彌國: 外道乃提頓綱網，抑揚辭義，誦其所執，待彼異論。

Here since 提頓 is used along side 抑揚 it should also be clear that it is a pair of antonym. Hence, your interpretation of "rising and pausing" is plausible.

Answer (score 1):

[**提顿**](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8F%90%E9%A1%BF/8795127#:%7E:text=%E6%8F%90%E9%A1%BF_%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%99%BE%E7%A7%91&text=%E6%8F%90%E9%A1%BF%EF%BC%8C%E8%AF%BB%E9%9F%B3%E6%98%AFt%C3%AD,%E8%BF%90%E7%AC%94%E7%9A%84%E6%8F%90%E8%B5%B7%E6%8C%89%E4%B8%8B%E3%80%82) - 书法术语。指运笔的提起按下。**亦喻文章的自然起伏**。

在主语后面，加上助词“者”表示提顿，谓语后加语气词“也”，加强判断语气。这是古代汉语判断句的典型结构。“**……者，……也**”是文言判断句最常见的形式。如：

- “陈涉者，阳城人也。” (史记·陈涉世家)
- ”莲，花之君子者也。” (周敦颐·爱莲说)
- “南冥者，天池也。”（庄子·逍遥游）
- “吾所欲者，土地也。”（韩非子·五蠹）
- “陈胜者，阳城人也。”（史记·陈涉世家）